# Shiny server: Track when user navigates from app

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a shiny dashboard app running on the open source shiny server which opens in a browser. The users then provide a username and password in order to view their respective dashboards. I would like to know when a user navigates away from the page or closes the browser window. I know I can use shinyjs's onevent feature but am not sure how to go about it. The pseudo code I have in mind is as below:

```
    name=input$username
    start_time=Sys.time()
    onevent("user navigates away/ closes the browser")
    end_time=Sys.time()
    write.table(name,start_time,end_time)
```

Appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `session$onEnded` to register a callback to run once the client disconnects.

```
shinyApp(
  ui    = shinyUI(fluidPage()),
  server= shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    session$onEnded(function(){
      # I will be called after the client has disconnected
      print('closed')
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: in the open source version of the Shiny server you cannot time out a session. I already have the session$onEnded block in my code, but it's of no use. That is why I was wondering if I could register an event when the user closes the browser or navigates away from the page.